# File exists, if statement checks, wont return correct output if file doesnt exist, C#

Tags: c#, file, error-handling, file-exists

I have a nested `if-else` statement that is checking the contents of a folder I have that contains other `txt` files. This method either creates new `txt` files or denies access if they already exist in the folder.

The trouble I am having is with the checks if the file exists in the folder. Currently no matter what I do, the command will always return "Filename already exists" even if it doesn't exist.

If the file does not exist then the program should go down to the `else` statement and then create the new file

```
protected void create(string command, string param1)
{
    // creates an empty file w/ default permissions
    // if file already exists then error message displayed in console

    //checks name of the file, checks if its exists, and if clear, creates the file
    if (param1 == "accounts.txt" || param1 == "audit.txt" || param1 == "groups.txt" || param1 == "files.txt")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot use this filename");
        Console.Read();
        return;
    }
    else if (File.Exists(@"C:\Files\"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Filename already exists");
        Console.Read();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\Files\", param1);
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            Console.Write("create " + param1 + "");
            string path2 = "C:\\Files\\audit.txt";
            using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.AppendText(path2))
            {
                sw2.WriteLine("File " + param1 + " with owner and default permissions created"); //append name of current login from memory
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This block here is saying if the File doesn't exist, then write to the console 'File already exists'

```
else if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Files\"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File already exists");
                Console.Read();
                return;
            }
```

Also note that you're using File.Exists on a directory, and not actually looking at a specific file.

See also Directory.Exists

[MSDN - Directory Exists method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry that should be "(File.Exists(@"C:\Files\")). It is checking a directory if a text file exists there. If the filename has already been taken, it throws an error. I updated the question

Comment: @l.redir Closer, but your code is still doing File.Exists on a directory.  In the else you're doing Path.Combine to build the full path.  You need to use the full Path to the file in the File.Exists() call in order to check if that File name has already been used.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the file name in the code. The string `@"C:\Files\")` is not a file name, it is a directory.

You can use something like.

```
internal static bool FileOrDirectoryExists(string name)
{
    return (Directory.Exists(name) || File.Exists(name));
}
```

To call the method, you have to pass the valid file name.

```
var name = Path.Combine( @"C:\Test","MyFile.txt");
var ifFileExist = FileOrDirectoryExists(name);
```

Comment: In this case though, "param1" is the filename that I am passing as a parameter. So would I do something like: 
var name = Path.Combine( @"C:\Test",param1);
var ifFileExist = FileOrDirectoryExists(name);

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer if it is helpful. Regards.